# How to insert shape into specified cell using "for each shape in activesheet.shapes" in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

I am asking for hint with following problem. How to add to specified cells shapes from activesheet? I am able to add shape when I know the name but don't know how to implement forumla for each shape in...

Currently I have something like this:

```
Sub loop()

Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim c As Integer

For a = 1 To 10
    For b = 1 To 10

        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape("Shape_Name", Cells(a, b), Cells(j, k), 10).Select

    Next a
Next b
End Sub
```

But I need something using this:

```
For Each Shape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
```

Comment: How can you refer to a shape in a for loop when it is not added yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what you need but try this

```
Dim shp As Shape

For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    Debug.Print shp.Name
Next
```

This only iterates over the Shapes collection. So you need to have shapes in place in order to access them => logical.

If you are trying to add shapes you can't use the `for each` in `.Shapes` as the `.Shapes` collection would have been empty.

---

So once you know the shapes name you can

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Rectangle 1").Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("B2").Select
Sheets(2).Paste
```

Comment: `If you are trying to add shapes you can't use the for each in .Shapes as the .Shapes collection would have been empty.` So very true :)

Comment: Ok. So what if I have some shapes in one worksheet and want to use them in other worksheet?

Comment: the you need to qualify the sheet so replace `ActiveSheet.Shapes` with `Sheets("Sheet name").Shapes` to iterate over shapes collection in "Sheet name". What do you mean you *want to use them* ?

Comment: To insert them into cells.